# Multiple categories for hc_yAxis

Tags: r, list, dataframe, highcharts, yaxis

tried now for a long time but can't find a solution.
I try to get something similar to that one:

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parallel-coordinates

So I have multiple Y-Axis with different categorial variables. But in R I can just define the first Axis. No idea why my solution doesn't work. Here an example:

```
library(highcharter)

df2 <- data.frame(name = c(2,2,2),y = c(0,1,2))
df3 <- data.frame(name = c(3,3,3),y = c(1,1,3))
df4 <- data.frame(name = c(4,4,4),y = c(2,0,1))

hc <- highchart()%>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = list("From","Node","To"))%>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = "xy",type = "spline", parallelCoordinates = TRUE)%>%
  hc_title(text = 'Marathon set')%>%
  # hc_yAxis(categories = list("S12","S19","S16"))%>%
  hc_yAxis(categories = list(
    list(categories = list("S12","S10","S16")),
    list(categories = list("A3","A5","B7")),
    list(categories = list("S15","S16","S20"))))%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "test2", data = df2)%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "test3", data = df3)%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "test4", data = df4)
hc
```

You see, the output isn't what I expect on the second and thirth Y-Axis.

I hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot define categories array with multiple categories arrays inside. You need to define a separate y-axes using `hc_yAxis_multiples`:

```
library(highcharter)

df2 <- data.frame(name = c(2,2,2),y = c(0,1,2))
df3 <- data.frame(name = c(3,3,3),y = c(1,1,3))
df4 <- data.frame(name = c(4,4,4),y = c(2,0,1))

hc <- highchart()%>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = list("From","Node","To"))%>%
  hc_chart(zoomType = "xy",type = "spline", parallelCoordinates = TRUE)%>%
  hc_title(text = 'Marathon set')%>%
  # hc_yAxis(categories = list("S12","S19","S16"))%>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(categories = list("S12","S10","S16")),
    list(categories = list("A3","A5","B7")),
    list(categories = list("S15","S16","S20"))
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name = "test2", data = df2)%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "test3", data = df3)%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "test4", data = df4)
hc
```